# custom button - text alignment in the middle doesnt work

Tags: html, css, alignment

I have a custom button, now I want change the height of the button, but im not able to set the text in the middle of the bottom. I have tried and tried, nothing has changed. Some of my try, i have commented out in the centerize block.

```css
.xButton {
  width: 76px;
  height: 35px;
  /* set the height */
  position: relative;
  overflow: visible;
  padding: 0.5em 1em;
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
  margin: auto;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 #fff;
  font: 11px/normal sans-serif;
  color: #333;
  white-space: nowrap;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  background-color: #ececec;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#f4f4f4), to(#ececec));
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(#f4f4f4, #ececec);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(#f4f4f4, #ececec);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(#f4f4f4, #ececec);
  background-image: linear-gradient(#f4f4f4, #ececec);
  -moz-background-clip: padding;
  /* for Firefox 3.6 */
  background-clip: padding-box;
  border-radius: 0.2em;
  display: block;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 5px;
  /* IE hacks */
  zoom: 1;
}
.centerize {
  /* display: table-cell !important!;
    vertical-align: middle !important!;
    line-height: normal !important!;  */
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<a href="#button" class="xButton centerize">Button XY</a>
```

Comment: you could center your text by playing around with line-height or padding.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the `line-height` equal to the `height of the button` i.e. 35px and not normal as it corresponds to line height of the font used.

```
.centerize {
  line-height: 35px; /* Added */
  float: left;
}
```

[**JSfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/wnqL1ckk/)

```css
.xButton {
  width: 76px;
  height: 35px;
  /* set the height */
  position: relative;
  overflow: visible;
  padding: 0.5em 1em;
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
  margin: auto;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 #fff;
  font: 11px/normal sans-serif;
  color: #333;
  white-space: nowrap;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  background-color: #ececec;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#f4f4f4), to(#ececec));
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(#f4f4f4, #ececec);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(#f4f4f4, #ececec);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(#f4f4f4, #ececec);
  background-image: linear-gradient(#f4f4f4, #ececec);
  -moz-background-clip: padding;
  /* for Firefox 3.6 */
  background-clip: padding-box;
  border-radius: 0.2em;
  display: block;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 5px;
  /* IE hacks */
  zoom: 1;
}
.centerize {
  line-height: 35px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<a href="#button" class="xButton centerize">Button XY</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove

```
height: 35px;
```

And add some padding to the button

```
padding: 1em 1.5em;
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/5pp310x9/

Comment: This solution also change the width of the button.

Comment: Oh I didn't know you want to have fixed width. Apologies.

Remove height and set padding only for top and bottom.

https://jsfiddle.net/5pp310x9/1/

Comment: And if you want to have fixed height also, the answer Manoj Kumar gave would do the trick. :)

Answer (score 0):

Put your button text inside a div and add these properties to the div

```
vertical-align: middle;
display: table-cell;
height: 35px;
width: 76px;
```

This means that your html will look something like this

```
<a href="#button" class="xButton centerize" ><div style="
vertical-align: middle;
display: table-cell;
height: 35px;
width: 76px;">Button XY</div></a>
```